# what happens when i use barcode scanner for excel input

Tags: microsoft-excel, scanner

I have no clue what to expect will happen in my excel spreadsheet when I connect a bar code scanner to my windows7 pc and click the trigger.
Do I have to tell excel "look out for some stuff from the scanner", like cell programming or a macro? Or is all that handshaking done by the scanners software app and/or driver?

Please take me step by step: I've got a blank sheet. my scanner is plugged in. I click the scanner trigger aimed at a bar code. What happens next, or, what do I need to do to have something entered into the sheet?

Be aware, I care not what form the scanner data is, not even what type of bar code I'm reading. All I care about is when I click the trigger, will i get something entered into a cell. From that point the moon and stars are mine! I just need a boost to get to that point.

I'm trying to draw a path between what I know I can do in other apps to what could I do with excel.

In my simple dbm, I can program a field to wait for input. on input, move to next field. repeat this instruction in each field I intend to use.

Is there anything I can assign to a cell to do this, other than by macro?
If only by macro, can you offer a simple one that would do this?

Comment: Most scanners act like keyboards, they simply (with minor translations) type the barcode into whatever has the focus.

Comment: Dummy way to know what will happen: try it. It won't explode, I guarantee.

Comment: Thanks. Pls see my latest edit to my question. Your input is appreciated.

Comment: Roald's answer is better and will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You just need to **select** the cell, **scan** (pull the trigger), and whatever it reads will be typed into that cell.

Please remember that you still need to manually move between cells if you are planning to scan series of barcodes, like serial numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Pls see my latest edit to my question. Your input is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most barcode scanners act like keyboards. They scan the code, translate it into keypresses and send that to the active application. Some (most?) of the them can enable prefixes or suffixes on each scan through a command sheet, where you scan a series of barcodes to change the scanners behaviour. For example the  [Zebra DS475](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/how-do-i-enable-an-enter-key-carriage-return-line-feed-suffix-after-each-scan.html) can add a carriage return to each barcode scannned.

As the default behaviour of excel is to go to the next row, but same column,  on a return, that might already get you started on the right track. Search for barcode scanners that can enable a carriage return on scan.